# Why $G$ is not an algebra of sets in $R$? is $\sigma(G)$ Borel Sets?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

We define family $G$ by all finite unions of sets in the form of 
$(x,y), (-\infty,x), (y,+\infty), (-\infty,+\infty)$

Why $G$ is not an algebra of sets in $R$?

And why $\sigma(G)$ is the family of Borel Sets?

I am having trouble showing that $G$ is actually not an algebra of sets in $R$, and it seems interesting that the Borel sets can be generated by $\sigma(G)$, and why is that?

Answer (score 1):

An algebra is to be closed under taking complements. The complement of an open set $(a,b)$ is 
$$
(a,b)^c = (-\infty,a] \cup [b,\infty).
$$
This set cannot be described by a finite union of sets in $\textbf{G}$.

Comment: Do you know why the σ-algebra generated by G is the family of Borel sets?

Comment: @nmerfnsdv Because every open set is a countable union of elements of $G$, so the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $G$ is exactly the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the set of open sets - and this is just the definition of the Borel algebra.